# SparkR Error in UseMethod("predict")

Tags: r, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, sparkr

Following the ALS example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/R/spark.als.html)

...but running in distributed mode, e.g.

```
Sys.setenv("SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS"="--master yarn sparkr-shell")
spark <- sparkR.session(master = "yarn",
                    sparkConfig = list(
                      spark.driver.memory = "2g",
                      spark.driver.extraJavaOptions =
                        paste("-Dhive.metastore.uris=",
                              Sys.getenv("HIVE_METASTORE_URIS"),
                              " -Dspark.executor.instances=",
                              Sys.getenv("SPARK_EXECUTORS"),
                              " -Dspark.executor.cores=",
                              Sys.getenv("SPARK_CORES"),
                              sep = "")
                    ))


ratings <- list(list(0, 0, 4.0), list(0, 1, 2.0), list(1, 1, 3.0), list(1, 2, 4.0),list(2, 1, 1.0), list(2, 2, 5.0))
df <- createDataFrame(ratings, c("user", "item", "rating"))
model <- spark.als(df, "rating", "user", "item")
stats <- summary(model)
userFactors <- stats$userFactors
itemFactors <- stats$itemFactors
# make predictions
summary(model)
predicted <- predict(object=model, data=df)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "ALSModel"
```

Looking at the [source for 2.1.1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/R/pkg/R/mllib.R#L1560) the method seems to exist, and the `summary()` function that is defined directly above it works just fine.

I have tried with with Spark, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, and 2.2.0-rc6, all of which give the same result.  Also, this is not limited to the ALS model, calling `predict()` for any model gives the same error.

I also get the same error when I run it in local mode, e.g.

```
spark <- sparkR.session("local[*]")
```

Has anybody come across this problem before?

Comment: Are you running this locally or in a cluster via `spark-submit`? And why exactly you set all this submit arguments in-script? Are you explicitly using `library(SparkR) in your script`?

Comment: I'm running this is distributed mode, which is why the extra arguments are in the session().  And yes, I am explicitly calling `library(SparkR)` in the script.

Just to add, I solved it by using Spark 2.1.1 in the end, that was the only version I managed to get it working with.

Comment: Again, these extra arguments is not usual procedure (normally you provide them in the command line). And once you solved the issue, it is good practice to answer your own question, so that it may be useful for others in the future.

Comment: These arguments are required when spinning up Spark from within RStudio.

Comment: Not necessarily: https://www.nodalpoint.com/sparkr-in-cloudera-hadoop/

Comment: Did the solution work?? If yes, kindly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not reproduced exactly your error (I get a different one), most probably the problem is in the second argument of your `predict` call, which should be `newData`, and not `data` (see the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/spark.als.html)).

Here is an adaptation of your code for Spark 2.2.0 run locally from RStudio:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "/home/ctsats/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/R/lib") # change the path accordingly here

sparkR.session(sparkHome = "/home/ctsats/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7")      # and here

ratings <- list(list(0, 0, 4.0), list(0, 1, 2.0), list(1, 1, 3.0), list(1, 2, 4.0),list(2, 1, 1.0), list(2, 2, 5.0))
df <- createDataFrame(ratings, c("user", "item", "rating"))
model <- spark.als(df, "rating", "user", "item")
stats <- summary(model)
userFactors <- stats$userFactors
itemFactors <- stats$itemFactors
# make predictions
summary(model)
predicted <- predict(object=model, newData=df)  # newData here
showDF(predicted)
# +----+----+------+----------+
# |user|item|rating|prediction|
# +----+----+------+----------+
# | 1.0| 1.0|   3.0|  2.810426|
# | 2.0| 1.0|   1.0| 1.0784092|
# | 0.0| 1.0|   2.0|  1.997412|
# | 1.0| 2.0|   4.0| 3.9731808|
# | 2.0| 2.0|   5.0| 4.8602753|
# | 0.0| 0.0|   4.0| 3.8844662|
# +----+----+------+----------+
```

A simple `predict(model, df)` will also work.